# Navigate between pages inside Syncfusion SfTabView tab, but without losing the tab page tabs

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, syncfusion

I am working on a Xamarin. Forms application for iOS and Android (cross-platform)
I am working with a tabbed page which has 5 tabs at the bottom (custom render from the tabbed page)
My problem is, when I push another page on top of a tab page, the tabs at the bottom disappears.
Is there any way to keep the tabs visible when pushing new pages?

```
   <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollView>
                <Grid>
                    <tabView:SfTabView
                        
                        DisplayMode="ImageWithText"
                        TabHeight="64"
                        TabHeaderPosition="Bottom"
                        TabHeaderBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
                        VisibleHeaderCount="4"
                        EnableSwiping="False">
                        <tabView:SfTabView.SelectionIndicatorSettings>
                            <tabView:SelectionIndicatorSettings Color="#FFFFFF" Position="Bottom" StrokeThickness="-11"/>
                        </tabView:SfTabView.SelectionIndicatorSettings>
                        <tabView:SfTabItem
                            
                            Title="Home"
                            TitleFontColor="#999999"
                            TitleFontFamily="InterMedium"
                            TitleFontSize="11"
                            SelectionColor="#0094DE"
                            ImageSource="HomeGrey.png">
                            <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                                <MobileScriptApp:HomeScreen1/>
                            </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                        </tabView:SfTabItem>

                        <tabView:SfTabItem 
                            Title="Pickup"
                            TitleFontColor="#999999"
                            TitleFontFamily="InterMedium"
                            TitleFontSize="11"
                            SelectionColor="#0094DE"
                            ImageSource="PickupGrey.png">
                            <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Label Text="BLAnk TAb" TextColor="Black"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                        </tabView:SfTabItem>

                        <tabView:SfTabItem 
                            Title="Settings" 
                            TitleFontColor="#999999"
                            TitleFontFamily="InterMedium"
                            TitleFontSize="11"
                            SelectionColor="#0094DE"
                            ImageSource="settings.png">
                            <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                                <MobileScriptApp:SettingPage/>
                            </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                        </tabView:SfTabItem>

                        <tabView:SfTabItem 
                            Title="Support" 
                            TitleFontColor="#999999"
                            TitleFontFamily="InterMedium"
                            TitleFontSize="11"
                            SelectionColor="#0094DE"
                            ImageSource="SupportGrey.png">
                            <tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                                <MobileScriptApp:SupportPage/>
                            </tabView:SfTabItem.Content>
                        </tabView:SfTabItem>
                    </tabView:SfTabView> 
                </Grid>
            </ScrollView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Are you trying to get the tabs you show to stay on screen when you go to another page? Maybe use a xamarin `TabbedPage` instead of a SyncFusion `SfTabView`. Say more about why you want the same tabs to show, when you navigate to another page.

Comment: because it is a demand of my project that's why.

Comment: That doesn't add any additional information. Without more details, all I can do is repeat the suggestion to use `TabbedPage`, which is designed to keep a set of tabs on screen, while changing pages. `SfTabView` has a different use; it is a "self-contained" description of content that can be brought up, as you click on tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The SfTabView doesn't support the reported behavior.

Since the SfTabView control is a ContentView control, it can be added to a ContentPage. Due to this, if we navigate to another page, the SfTabView will not be visible because it is a child of another page.

Thanks,
Vijayakumar V